# Selecting multiple dates across multiple months in the asp calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, calendar

I have encountered the following issue with asp calender.

Currently, I am able to select multiple dates within the range (which I have set) which is within 1 month. However I am unable to get the correct selected dates if my range is within 2 months (cross month).

Within 2 months:

If my calendar displays at the 1st month, I can still gets the dates from the 2 months but may have duplication dates on the 2nd months.

If my calendar display at the 2nd month, I am only able to get dates from the 2nd month.

Any advise for the above issue? Thanks in advance~ =)

```
protected void CalendarMain_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime minDate, maxDate;
            if (!tbStartDate.Text.Equals("") && !tbEndDate.Text.Equals(""))
            {

                minDate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbStartDate.Text);
                maxDate = Convert.ToDateTime(tbEndDate.Text);

                if (e.Day.Date < minDate || e.Day.Date > maxDate)
                {
                    e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                }

                if (e.Day.Date >= minDate && e.Day.Date.Date <= maxDate)
                {
                    e.Cell.BackColor = Color.FromName("#3f97ab");
                }


            }

            DataTable dtgv = Session["dtSelectedDateData"] as DataTable;
            if (dtgv != null)
            {

                foreach (DataRow drr in dtgv.Rows)
                {
                    string DateValue = drr["Time_Start"].ToString();

                    if (e.Day.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == DateValue.Substring(0, 10))
                    {
                        e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
                        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;

                    }
                }
            }
            if (e.Day.IsSelected == true)
            {

                PatientsSchedule.listDatetime.Add(e.Day.Date);      
            }
            Session["SelectedDate"] = PatientsSchedule.listDatetime;
        }

public static List<DateTime> listDatetime = new List<DateTime>();
```

Comment: jquery calendar? give some examples

Comment: I'm using asp calendar under the CalendarMain_DayRender method, and everytime a date is selected, it will add into a static <list>.

I have add my code in my question. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issues. Here's the trick, I added a new List<> in my class file and a conditions statement under the calender SelectionChanged. So it will capture value for every click.